# Sorting list of strings based on another list of strings

Tags: python, sorting

I have two list `x` and `y`. The former is always longer than or equal to the latter.

```
x = ["foo","bar","qux","zox"]
y1 = ["zox", "qux","foo"]
```

What I want to do is to sort `y1` based on the order of `x`.
Yielding

```
["foo","qux","zox"]
```

I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
In [10]: [x[1] for x in sorted(zip(x,y))]
Out[10]: ['zox', 'qux']
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: zipping isn't exactly going to yield anything close to what they were asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument of `sorted` to use the `index` from the first list.

```
>>> sorted(y1, key=x.index)
['foo', 'qux', 'zox']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through each element in `x` and add that element to a new list only if the corresponding element exists in `y1`.

```
>>> x = ["foo","bar","qux","zox"]
>>> y1 = ["zox", "qux","foo"]
>>> l = []
>>> for i in x:
        if i in y1:
            l.append(i)


>>> l
['foo', 'qux', 'zox']
```

**OR**

Use list_comprehension.

```
>>> [i for i in x if i in y1]
['foo', 'qux', 'zox']
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that depending how large your list is `.index` requires a linear scan, and can be expensive. You may just create a one off dictionary of key->last index, and then use that as a reference to sort:

```
x = ["foo","bar","qux","zox"]
y1 = ["zox", "qux","foo"]

y1.sort(key=lambda L, d={k:i for i,k in enumerate(x)}: d[L])
# ['foo', 'qux', 'zox']
```

However, you could also do it the other way around, which could well be more efficient... Convert `y1` to set then only keep elements also in `x`, eg:

```
filter(set(y1).__contains__, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a [custom comparator for when sorting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable), like so:

```
x = ["foo","bar","qux","zox"]
y1 = ["zox", "qux","foo"]

def foo_sort(a,b):
   return x.index(a)-x.index(b)
y1.sort(cmp=foo_sort)

print y1
```

Gives:

```
['foo', 'qux', 'zox']
```